# SQL insert parameter value bit or datetime getting error syntax near @variablename

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, parameters, bit

Ok so I'm having a good connection with SQL server. I have spent a couple of hours looking through the questions already asked and I have tried pretty much everything. From String.Format my query and I have come to the conclusion that I need to parametrize the query from multiple comments. I have tested with nvarchar type variable and it works. The problem I have is when I add the types bit and datetime. I don't know which one is the problem. Probably the bit one since the error message is :

Incorrect syntax near `@Afficher`

which is of bit parameter

Here is the code :

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connexion))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
                "INSERT INTO Actualite (Titre, Sous_titre, Contenu, Image, Vignette, Video, Date_publication, Afficher) " +
                "VALUES (@Titre, @Sous_titre, @Contenu, @Image, @Vignette, @Video, @Date_publication, @Afficher", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Titre", "Ceci est un test"));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Sous_titre", "Ceci est un test"));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Contenu", "Ceci est un test, ça l'air à marcher"));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Image", "minecraft.jpg"));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Vignette", "vminecraft.jpg"));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Video", "NULL"));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date_publication", SqlDbType.DateTime)).Value = DateTime.Now;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Afficher", SqlDbType.Bit)).Value = 1;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

I have tried using 1 and true as the parameter value and still get the error. My head is about to explode...

Comment: Your insert statement is missing the closing parenthesis at the end of the values clause...

Comment: Yes, the error message can't be more specific than that...I'm ashamed...Thanks alot :)

Comment: It's the kind of things you just need a fresh pair of eyes to look at your code, happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your insert statement is missing the closing parenthesis at the end of the values clause.

Also, if you intended the `Video` column to contain `NULL` after the insert statement, you should simply omit it from the columns list and the variables list, so your code should look like this:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connexion))
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "INSERT INTO Actualite (Titre, Sous_titre, Contenu, Image, Vignette, Date_publication, Afficher) " +
    "VALUES (@Titre, @Sous_titre, @Contenu, @Image, @Vignette, @Date_publication, @Afficher)", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Titre", "Ceci est un test"));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Sous_titre", "Ceci est un test"));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Contenu", "Ceci est un test, ça l'air à marcher"));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Image", "minecraft.jpg"));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Vignette", "vminecraft.jpg"));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date_publication", SqlDbType.DateTime)).Value = DateTime.Now;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Afficher", SqlDbType.Bit)).Value = 1;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Ok but I need the parameter on every query, is this the right way or do i need to pass as null without the quotes? The Video parameter is only a string with a Url. Will eventually make a verification and pass the value or null at this point.

Comment: You don't need to specify it at all if you are only going to hard code `null` to it's parameter. If you want to, you can set the parameter value to `DBNull.Value`, but it's just adding meaningless code unless you have some sort of condition on the value of that parameter.

Comment: Yes that's it I'm gonna make a condition but for now I'm just testing